# Doctrine "relation does not exist" error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two doctrine entities (Company and Supplier) linked together by a CompanySupplier entity.  Entities and yaml resources are as below:

```
class Company
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

}

class Supplier
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

}    

class CompanySupplier
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $company_id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $supplier_id;

}
```

My resources are as below:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Company:
  type: entity
  table: companies
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
  manyToMany:
    Suppliers:
      targetEntity: Supplier
      joinTable:
        name: company_suppliers
        joinColumns:
          company_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          supplier_id:
            referencedColumnName: id


AppBundle\Entity\Supplier:
  type: entity
  table: suppliers
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
  fields:
    name:
      type: string

AppBundle\Entity\CompanySupplier:
  type: entity
  table: company_suppliers
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
  fields:
    company_id:
      type: integer
    supplier_id:
      type: integer
  ManyToMany:
    Supplier:
      targetEntity: Supplier
      joinColumn:
        name: id
        referencedColumnName: supplier_id
```

The problem is this seems to cause a “relation company_supplier does not exist” error which I can’t see how to resolve.  What do I need to do to set the relations up so that these work?

It works if I don't have the CompanySupplier entity and resource, but as soon as I define those errors start appearing.

I'd appreciate any pointers this is driving me mad.

Answer (score 0):

do change the namespaces and you don't need to write the relational table i think
[see here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

```
Company:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
    supplier:
      targetEntity: CompanySupplier
      inversedBy: company
      joinTable:
        name: company_suppliers
        joinColumns:
          name: id
          referencedColumnName: supplier_id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          supplier_id:
            referencedColumnName: id

Supplier:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
    company:
      targetEntity: Company
      mappedBy: supplier
```